# Google auth2 access token gets dots(.) after the token time to time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-authentication

I'm trying to get an access token from https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token to access the google bucket. Code was wroking without any issue. Yesterday the application suddenly broke up. Then I notice this below issue that API returns .......... after the token. The issue gets from time to time.
[image]

Comment: Please include your code. Presumably (although you don't state it) this causes an issue. Be careful not to publish tokens. My initial concern is that I suspect you're not (but you really should be) using one of Google's SDKs to access the service.

Comment: I opened a support ticket about the issue. "gcloud auth print-access-token" results same dotted output.

Answer (score 3):

I found that Google informed customers about the issue via e-mail in May 2021. You can read the mail content, someone shared on the web, see the following [link](https://github.com/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy/issues/1218).

> On August 23, 2021, we will roll out security and reliability improvements that will increase the sizes of OAuth 2.0 access tokens for all projects.
>
> Unlike the specially padded tokens that were sent during the verification phase, these tokens will not have a padding and the token itself will be larger compared to current tokens.

Google experiments changing the token size with placeholder characters (periods) in the *"verification phase"* but will remove the placeholders and increase the token size at the specified date.

Placeholders do not belong to the token. So, removing the padding does not invalidate the token.

> The overall access token size will continue to remain within the 2048 bytes limit documented in Google’s Developer guide and public documentation.

Increased size may not be as long as the placeholders. But you should ensure that your program can handle the tokens within the limits.